# Fast computation of linear equation with row and column removed

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

Given $A, x, b$ and a linear system $Ax=b$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is full rank. Denote $A_{\backslash i}$ as a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix where $A$ removes its $i^{th}$ column and row, similarly $b_{\backslash i}$. What's the most efficient way to find a $y$ for each $i\in[n]$ s.t $A_{\backslash i}y=b_{\backslash i}$? (So in total these are $n$ linear systems, for different $i$ I want a different solution $y$).

I know one way is to use Sherman-Morrison formula, but is there any way that doesn't involve calculating $A^{-1}$? That is, suppose I have $x$ calculated, can $y$ be derived just using $A, x, b$?

Comment: When you write, "Given a linear system $Ax=b$," do you mean, given all three of $A,x,b$? When you write "find $A_{\backslash i}y=b_{\backslash i}$", do you mean "find $y$"?

Comment: Yes to both questions, I have modified the question.

Comment: Why don't you want to use $A^{-1}$ (or an equivalent factorization)? It seems the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Such $y$ may not exist.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Because my $A$ is huge and inverse takes too long

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Maybe I wasn't being super clear in the OP. I want to find different $y$ for different $i$. So in total, there are $n$ solutions $y$. They should always exist because $A_{\backslash i}$ is full rank.

Comment: So is your matrix sparse or dense? How big is "huge"? How would you solve linear systems with $A$ or $A_{\setminus i}$ normally; with a direct or an iterative method?

Comment: How would you use Sherman-Morrison formula?

Comment: @user3799934: Consider matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $x=b=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. What is $y$, say, for $i=1$?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I see. For my particular case it's safe to assume that $A_{\backslash i}$ has full rank for any $i$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni it's roughly 80k*80k and dense. The issue is mostly with memory, I assume existing linear system solvers use iterative methods? Taking inverse seems to load the whole matrix into memory.

Comment: @VítTuček Taking a row and column off is a rank-2 update so I can write $A_{\backslash i}=A+UV$ for some $U, V$ (it's slightly different because here i'm setting rows/columns to 0 rather than deleting them). Then apply the woodbury matrix identity (or maybe just apply Sherman morrison twice). This concerns me because it seems to require calculating $(I+UA^{-1}V)^{-1}$ $n$ times because $U, V$ vary.

Comment: @user3799934 Ouch; that seems a difficult problem by every metric. I don't think you can avoid essentially running a dense $O(n^3)$ inversion algorithm to solve that problem. You wish to solve various $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ linear systems anyway, so there's no getting around that.

Comment: @user3799934 Keep in mind that $I+UA^{-1}V$ is $2\times 2$, so that computation is cheap; the SMW update procedure costs $O(n^2)$ per linear solve. I'd guess that you can do the whole procedure (producing $n$ different vectors $y_{\setminus i}$) in something like $6n^3$ flops with SMW. The obvious lower bound is $\frac23 n^3$ flops for solving a single $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ linear system (barring Strassen-like tricks), so there is at most a small multiplicative factor to gain here, at least thinking in terms of flops.